# SQL loop to read, then write data to file

Tags: mysql, sql, r, plyr

I have a dataset that has 57 million rows and 23 columns. There is a column with species names of different birds (about 2000 unique names), and I would like to pull out two columns of data (latitude, longitude) for each unique species name, and write to file the lat/long data for each species, with the species name as the file name. This takes too long to do from R, the only language I know. What would the appropriate code be for this task?

I am attempting some pseudo-code here to demonstrate what I am guessing the code might look like, roughly:

```
FOR i IN 1:unique(species_name)
    SELECT latitude,longitude WHERE species_name=[i]
    WRITE [some code that writes a text file with species name as the file name]
LOOP END;
```

I imagine I can do this sort of thing in Terminal on OSX?

EDIT 20111211:
Here is my workflow from R:

```
 require(RMySQL);
 require(plyr)
 drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
 con <- dbConnect(drv, user = "asdfaf", dbname = "test", host = "localhost")
 splist <- read.csv("splist_use.csv")
 sqlwrite <- function(spname) {
   cat(spname) g1 <- dbGetQuery(con
     , paste("SELECT col_16,col_18 FROM dat WHERE col_11='"
     , spname, "'", sep="")
     )
   write.csv(g1, paste(spname, ".csv", sep=""))
   rm("g1") }
 l_ply(splist, sqlwrite, .progress="text" )
```

Comment: What SQL server are you using? Most offer an export feature which would be far faster I think in your particular case.

Comment: MySQL. The only GUI interface I have is SequelPro.

Comment: Right, I could export, but I would have to filter on the species, and then export, then do that 2000 times, which is a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best thing you can do is use a scripting language (python, perl, php, shell) and generate the filenames and queries from there. It is not too difficult, but you will have to learn a different language. SQL is not suitable for imperative programming.

Comment: Okay.  I was hoping for an R solution, calling MySQL from R, but I should probably learn the appropriate language for this specific problem.

Comment: If you are comfortable with R, use R. I know there is a postgres-interface to R, there could be a mysql interface, too. Just post what you've got, and people can help you with either the R part or the sql part or the interface part. For your sanity: access the database as a "read only", or work on a copy of the database, or make sure you have a backup.

Comment: Here is my workflow from Rrequire(RMySQL); require(plyr)
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user = "asdfaf", dbname = "test", host = "localhost")

splist <- read.csv("splist_use.csv")

sqlwrite <- function(spname) {
    cat(spname)
    g1 <- dbGetQuery(con, 
        paste("SELECT col_16,col_18 FROM dat WHERE col_11='", spname, "'", sep=""))
    write.csv(g1, paste(spname, ".csv", sep=""))
    rm("g1")
}

l_ply(splist, sqlwrite, .progress="text")

Comment: Just add an empty line and indent code blocks with 4 spaces. BTW I added a ")", and cut it into lines to fit within the width of the form; hope that R allows multi-line statements like this (I don't know R). Is the code block complete now?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MySQL outfile functionality?

```
SELECT col_16,col_18 
FROM 
dat 
WHERE col_11= spiecesname
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/spiecesname.csb'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

With a little bit of work you could make MySQL pick out each unique Species name, loop through the results and output to a unique csv file.

You should have an order by clause on your query

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the tip.  I found a solution a while back using PHP and MySQL from a friend, but this is nice.

Answer (score 0):

is an Excel file output acceptable and do you have excel? If so you can use Excel to connect to the database, and issue a your query to extract the data.  it's then in .xls or csv. format. However this assumes you results  are less than 1,000,000.

In excel
go to data tab
select from other sources
select and enter preferred method of connection
From here you can define a table or query to run.  (if results are less than the number of rows supported on the sheet for the excel version you are on) then using the method you've selected will extract the files.  Should be faster than the IO your currently doing.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware this was possible. I already used a PHP/MySQL solution, but this a good alternative solution.